# Sammyjs routes not working with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, sammy.js

I have built an app with SammyJs. It currently works perfectly in the browser. However, when I package it to Android using PhoneGap, the routes does not work anymore.

I have found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034811/sammy-js-app-link-routing-not-working-in-phonegap). However, the solution given does not work :

```
(function($) {

    var app = $.sammy('[role=main]', function() {
      this.disable_push_state = true;
      ...
    });
}
```

Has anyone ever experienced the same issue?

**EDIT**

I am also using jquery mobile with the following script to disable its routing :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      // DISABLE JQM ROUTER
      $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
      });
    </script>
```

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/BR41N1/6342231) with my app sammy javascript (including routes).

Comment: Could you provide the code where you define your routes?

Comment: I updated my answer with a gist.

Comment: You are changing the URL from localhost to the right hostname/ip before uploading to your phone, right? `url = 'http://localhost:3000/api.json?school=' + localStorage.school`

Comment: I checked and I currently am fetching a file data.api instead of my server.

Comment: Have you tried logging something (or alerting) in a `get` callback? To pinpoint if the error is because of routing or templating.

Comment: I did. I can't log because it's on mobile. I did put some alerts though. The app is running. However, the index route (or any other routes) is not catched

Comment: If you get the same results on in mobile chrome you can use Remote Debugging (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging). Also see: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Comment: Please update the tag with phonegap that will attract the phonegap experts

Comment: I dont know SammyJs, but as i see in the documentation "Sammy is samll web framework", so you need to call links and stuff like this. To call a link you should add it first in the whitelist, plus it's true that Cordova works as local server as concept, but it's not local server, so when you'll request a file you should use it's name directly without the "http://localhost:8080"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this around clause:

```
this.around(function(callback) {
  var context = this;

  url = 'http://localhost:3000/api.json?school=' + localStorage.school

  this.load(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      parsed = JSON.parse(data);

      //if (parsed.meta != undefined) {
      //  alert(parsed.meta.message);
      //}
      context.products = parsed.products;
      context.places = parsed.places;
      context.school = parsed.school;
      context.title = $('[data-role=header] h1');
    })
    .then(callback); // *** this won't get called if load() rejects promise
});
```

As I understand it, the around clause is called with a callback(), which will continue loading the route when it is called.

I think there is a problem with your promise chain. If load() returns a rejected promise (which probably does, as there is no localhost:3000 on your phone), then neither of your then() functions will load. As such, callback() isn't called and the app "stops". I would advise (a) adding some error handling there, so you can see what it happening, and definitely (b) executing callback no matter the result of load(). Also - JSON.parse(data) will throw an error if data is not a proper JSON-encoded string - you want a try/catch around that, too.

I would try this:

```
this.load(url)
.then(function(data) {
  try {
     parsed = JSON.parse(data);
  } catch(e) {
     console.log('error decoding json!: '+errorMsg);
  }

  //if (parsed.meta != undefined) {
  //  alert(parsed.meta.message);
  //}
  context.products = parsed.products;
  context.places = parsed.places;
  context.school = parsed.school;
  context.title = $('[data-role=header] h1');
},function(errorMsg){
  console.log('error loading json!: '+errorMsg);
})
.fin(callback); // *** fin() is meant to execute on both success and error, like a "finally".
```

If your promises implementation does not support fin(), look up what it is calling its equivalent. It is essentially shorthand for: `.then(callback).otherwise(callback)`

Long story short - you want to make sure that the callback passed to around will be executed no matter what, or you app will not continue loading the route, which is what your unexpected behaviour seems to be.

As for the point about not being able to see the console, I am not sure what your environment looks like, but I have had success with Eclipse and ADT in the past - I can see console logs and errors just fine.

Comment: My problem is solved. However, I find JQM extremely slow with PhoneGap and I don't like that I have to fight against the framework. I might change my views and keep Sammy...

Comment: This may not be applicable to your case, but I've often found that the  "apparent" responsiveness of it has a lot to do with the hover/tap timeouts. If it is slow responding to taps, check the [jqm docs on cordova](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/how-configure-phonegap-cordova.html) if you haven't already. Try tweaking your $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay function. It is purposefully waiting around for a few hundred ms to distinguish hover/tap - if you don't have hoverable elements you could turn that down and have your app feel more responsive.

Comment: better answer than my previous attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024464/speeding-up-page-transitions-in-jquery-mobile-1-1-for-iphone-apps-built-with-pho (make sure you match your jqm version)

Comment: I did notice a difference, particularly with the click-delay.